# Angular material (@angular/material) components don't look like they have to

Tags: angular, angular-material

I Updated Angular and Angular Material to the 9th version and I do like the new look of the angular material components, but having updated i didn't see any changes, my components look like they were before.

I have a problem with the `mat-select` component, for example.

It looks like:[looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/708Br.png)

But it has to look like:[has to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgdO.png)

So, is there anyone who has the same problem and can help me with it?

Comment: Please attach a source code from that element please.

Comment: @JorgeMussato, the source code is exactly the same as in the documentation, https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form fields have four different styles - you need to provide the one you want, or set it manually on each of them: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

[image: form field styles]!